# Is there a way for an XML file to tell IE10 to use compatibility view?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer-10, ie-compatibility-mode

I have the following local XML file (not served by a web server), which contains an embedded style block :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="#style" type="text/css"?>
<bitext version="1.2">
    <st id="style">
        none { }
        bitext { font-family: Arial; }
        title { position: fixed; width: 100%; display: block; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: #fff; background-color: #0082b8; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
        st { display: none; }
        segments { margin: 5px; margin-top: 30px; display: table; font-size: 10pt; }
        seg { display: block; clear: both; margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 6px; }
        src { float: left; margin: 0; width: 48%; padding: 6px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 1px solid #ddd;  }
        tgt { float: right; margin: 0; width: 48%; padding: 6px; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 1px solid #ddd;  }
    </st>
    <meta>
        <title>Document Title</title>
    </meta>
    <segments>
        <seg>
            <src><b>Sample-e.doc</b></src>
            <tgt><b>Sample-f.doc</b></tgt>
        </seg>
        <seg match="1-1" id="1">
            <src>Sample sentence</src>
            <tgt>Phrase d'exemple</tgt>
        </seg>
    </segments>
</bitext>
```

This XML file displays properly, with expected styling, in IE8 but requires Compatibility View to display correctly in IE10.

Is there a way to tell IE10 to use Compatibility View IN THE XML?  I know I can force Compatibility View in "Tools", "Compatibility View settings" or with "Tools", "F12 developer tools", but I would much prefer to have a seamless solution...

Searching the web, I'm having a hard time finding information about such embedded style in XML (maybe it's a hint that we shouldn't use it...).  Tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`, but obviously XML doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Like you already guessed, embedded style in XML is not really standard...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

are the only correct ways to "force" compatibility view as far as I'm aware.

To get IE8 rendring you can however use

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Emulate8" />`

Comment: Make sure to close your META tag, XML requires all tags to be closed... Edited my answer to reflect this, my apologies and you should be declaring it right after the Character Encoding (along with the other meta tags you might use)

Answer (score 0):

The `X-UA-Compatible` flag can be specified as an HTTP header as well as via a meta tag.

If your content isn't HTML, the meta tag option isn't available, so I suggest using the HTTP header option instead.

How you'd actually set that up will depend on what server software you're using, so I won't go into the specifics of how to configure it, but hopefully you'll be able work it out from here.

Comment: It's a stand alone, local XML file - it's not served by a server - so there's no HTTP header.

Comment: ah, that's a shame as it's the only other real way to make it switch mode. Not sure what else to suggest. I guess fixing the stylesheet so it renders correctly in IE10 mode is out of the question?

Comment: I'm not having any luck with various values of the `X-UA-Compatible` HTTP header, either.